# Is there a way for automatic text insertion in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I use some words as tags inside a Word document. Is there a way to save those so when I write first and second letter of them then it will automatically suggest that word for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for Auto Correct.
Here is how to reach it:

- Click menu *File > Options*
- Position to *Proofing*
- Click "AutoCorrect Options..."
- In the AutoCorrect tab, enter "Replace:" "With:" for your
  abbreviations
- Click OK.

References :

- [Turn AutoCorrect on or off in Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/turn-autocorrect-on-or-off-in-word-9f5a0684-05f6-4510-b419-8f0034cae)
- [Add or remove AutoCorrect entries in Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/add-or-remove-autocorrect-entries-in-word-e7433b94-f3de-4532-9dc8-b29063a96e1f)

Answer (score 0):

### There are two Word features that do something like what you are asking for: AutoCorrect and AutoComplete

In neither case should you normally set the trigger to be something that you normally type because you will get accidental insertions.

Here are links to my page on these features:

- [AutoCorrect](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#AutoCorrect)
- [AutoComplete](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#AutoComplete) *(for AutoText and other Building Blocks)*

Here are some more links:

- [Exploiting AutoCorrect](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/AutoCorrect.htm) by Suzanne Barnhill, Word MVP
- [Create Reusable Text Snippets](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-reusable-text-snippets-0bc40cab-f49c-4e06-bcb2-cd43c1674d1b) by Microsoft Support
- [Building Blocks and AutoText](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-reusable-text-snippets-0bc40cab-f49c-4e06-bcb2-cd43c1674d1b) by Greg Maxey

Both of these provide for the ability of the user to type something and bring in something else. The *something else* can be text or even images or pages.

You want to have the trigger or key be something that you would not type ordinarily. I will often start with and underscore or other character that is not ordinarily part of a word.

AutoText/Building Blocks can be stored in templates and are much easier to transfer to another computer or share with someone else. AutoCorrect will insert instantly upon pressing the space bar or punctuation, while AutoComplete will want the user to either press Enter or the F3 key.

AutoText/Building Blocks can also easily be included in drop-down lists using the [Building Blocks Gallery Content Control](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#BBGalleryContentControl). This is not something that can be done with AutoCorrect entries.

Also, AutoCorrect will be proofing-language specific while AutoText/Building Blocks are not.

.